# Am I not deploying Celery correctly?

Tags: python, django, deployment, redis, celery

I deployed DRF with celery on Render (which uses Gunicorn) and celery tasks don't work. Only when I remove .delay() when calling the function, it works. So the email sending function is correct.

Tasks are getting created properly (Railway server), but in server logs the print() statement is not shown on a task creation
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBqwU.png)

Folder structure:

```
|-base
  |-tasks.py
|-manager
  |-celery.py
  |-wsgi.py
  |-settings.py
```

I'm creating a task like this in tasks.py:

```
from celery import shared_task
from time import sleep
import os, ssl, smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

@shared_task
def send_the_email():
    sleep(10)
    email_sender = <my email>
    email_password = <password, which I generated on two step verification>

    em = EmailMessage()
    em['From'] = email_sender
    em['To'] = <another email of mine>
    em['Subject'] = 'subject'
    em.set_content('body')
    
    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
        smtp.login(email_sender, email_password)
        smtp.sendmail(email_sender, <another email of mine>, em.as_string())
```

views.py:

```
from base.tasks import send_the_email
class index(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def get(req,self):
        send_the_email.delay()
        return Response({'msg': 'hi'})
```

Any suggestions?